# How do I use Rails Selectize in my Rails Project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selectize.js, rails-assets

I'm getting the error

```
Selectize: Dependency MicroPlugin is missing

Make sure you either: (1) are using the "standalone" version of Selectize, or (2) require MicroPlugin before you load Selectize.
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require selectize
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed my application.js to

```
//= require selectize/standalone/selectize
```

I figured it out by looking at the load paths

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rails-assets-selectize-0.12.3/app/assets/javascripts
```

and found standalone was in `/selectize/standalone/selectize.js`

I knew to look there by looking at [their examples](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/contacts.html#L16).

Comment: I had the same problem. My mistake was that I linked the selectize.js file that is outside of standalone directory, linking it to the one in standalone directory solved the problem for me.